# Blank page with web browser (error 500), fine with php command

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$im = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/banner.png");
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Commands that work:

```
sudo -u www-data php banner.php > test.png
php banner.php > test.png (as root)
```

These produce a file that can be seen with a web browser. Any ideas?

There's nothing in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Setting display_errors = On fixes the issue.
Setting it back to off and restarting also fixes the issue
Seems fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was sorted after turning on display_errors, restarting apache, turning it back off again and then restarting again.

Answer (score 0):

you have a permissions issue going on here since the file or directory was created with root apache will not have the proper permission

you could do the following if permissions is the issue:

```
chown nobody:nogroup -R /var/www/
```

Comment: This can't be the case as I did "sudo -u www-data php banner.php > test.png" and it worked fine.

Comment: The issue was sorted after turning on display_errors, restarting apache, turning it back off again and then restarting again.